# Webpage automatically scrolls to the first enabled element

Tags: jquery, scroll, html

On my web page, I disable all my fields using jquery on form load except one at the bottom of the page which is enabled and the page automatically scrolls to the bottom of the page.

How can I keep the scroll at the top of the page even if the only enabled field is in the bottom of the page?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/focus/

Comment: $(window).scrollTop(0); ???

Comment: Tried that..doesnt work unfortunately..

Comment: And how do you try it? Because should work if used correctly but as you didn't post any relevant code, its quite impossible to help you...

Answer (score 0):

use scroll element .scrollTop() function of jquery